# How do you extract characters from a string?

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to send emails from my google sheet. I want the emails to address recipients by their first name or the name they are known by. The following is an example of my data in column A.

[image: Sample Data]

I need a formula in column B that extracts the first name from column A but if they are known by a different name, the name in the brackets in column A, then I want that name extracted to column B instead. I have the following formula which works for names in brackets but I need help with the formula to extract the first name when there are no brackets.

```
=(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\((.*)\)"),","))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one-cell solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(IFNA(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\((.*)\)"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, ", (.*)"))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

Try this. In B2, enter this formula:

```
=iferror(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\((.*)\)"),","), mid(A2, find(", ", A2)+2, len(A2)))
```

Explanation:

The first part is yours:
    SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"((.*))"),",")

As you've seen, this returns an #ERROR if the "(" isn't found. So use `iferror` to wrap that. The second part is returned if there is an error:
    =mid(A2, find(", ", A2)+2, len(A2))

The `mid()` function returns a substring from a string. The first argument is the string that you're looking in, found in `A2`. Then, The starting position of the substring is the location of ", " (offset by 2), and continues to the end of the string.

Comment: Perfect - thank you for your help and the explanation.

Comment: @McChief this works but you can also use index(split(A2:A," "),,2) see my answer for how to do it with an arrayformula so you do not have to drag down.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In B1, enter this formula:

```
={"Salutation";arrayformula(if(A2:A="","",iferror((SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"\((.*)\)"),",")),index(split(A2:A," "),,2))))}
```

Explanation:

The first part is yours: SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"((.*))"),",")

As you've seen, this returns an #ERROR if the "(" isn't found. So use iferror to wrap that. The second part is returned if there is an error: index(split(A2:A," "),,2)

The index() function returns the second column from the split(). The advantage to doing it this way is you will not have to drag formulas down.

Comment: thank you. In my actual spreadsheet column G is the Full Name and column I is the Salutation. I changed all of your code from A2:A to G3:G but I keep getting an error.

Comment: @McChief you have your headers on the second row or the first row? If you have your headers on the first row it should be G2:G

Comment: the headers are on the 3rd row

Comment: I changed the last 2 in your code to 3 but it still doesn't work

Comment: @McChief if the header is on the third row you need to change it to G4:G

Comment: Sorry the header is on the second row

Comment: @McChief can you make a small isolated sample and share a link with me?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wIaBnGmq-UG9UvAP9X4o-svo_SO1SElUhx6TSpdjgZw/edit?usp=sharing